# Ant build script executing <sql> task using java code

Tags: java, ant

Any idea, why none of the debugging comments are printed once after executing the ANT build script's SQL task via java code?

The java class to execute the sql in build scirpt is

```
public class AntRunnerTest {
   private Project project;

   public void executeTask(String taskName) {
      try {
        project = new Project();
        project.init();
        project.setBasedir(new String("."));
        ProjectHelper helper = ProjectHelper.getProjectHelper();
        project.addReference("ant.projectHelper", helper);
        helper.parse(project, new File("build-copy.xml"));
        System.out.println("Before");
        project.executeTarget(taskName);
        System.out.println("After");
      } catch(Exception ex) {
          System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
      }
   }

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      try {
         AntRunnerTest newInst = new AntRunnerTest();
         newInst.executeTask("sql");
      } catch(Exception e) { 
         System.out.println(""+e);
      }
   }
}
```

**I dont see the debug String "After"** getting printed in the console. I noticed this issue only when i try to execute a sql task using java code.

The ant script has the following simple transaction tag in it.

```
<transaction> <![CDATA[ select now() ]]> </transaction>
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure you override the sql task's "output" attribute value to some .txt file. That should resolve the problem.

Comment: @Jay - if you've answered the question, could you post the answer and accept it, so the question doesn't show up in lists of unanswered?

Comment: Hi. This code execute ant file name build-copy.xml. Is the file already exist or created on the fly?

Comment: @Iso, build-copy.xml is a ready to use/existing file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem will be solved if you add the output attribute of  tag.

Answer (score 0):

Example of an Ant build script executing any task using java code:

- direct the log to the console and byte array;
- fill in the Ant project variables;
- execute an ant task;
- add output log to swing component (javax.swing.JTextArea);

See source code: https://github.com/wellboyvg/workgear/blob/master/manager/src/manager/WorkGearManager.java

```
private boolean executeAntTask(String target) {
boolean success = false;
// use log output to the console
DefaultLogger conlog = new DefaultLogger();
conlog.setErrorPrintStream(System.err);
conlog.setOutputPrintStream(System.out);
conlog.setMessageOutputLevel(Project.MSG_INFO);
// use log output to the byte array
DefaultLogger strlog = new DefaultLogger();
ByteArrayOutputStream errb = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PrintStream errp = new PrintStream(errb);
strlog.setErrorPrintStream(errp);
ByteArrayOutputStream outb = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PrintStream outp = new PrintStream(outb);
strlog.setOutputPrintStream(outp);
strlog.setMessageOutputLevel(Project.MSG_INFO);
// prepare Ant
Project project = new Project();
File buildfile = new File(buildname);
project.setUserProperty("ant.file", buildfile.getAbsolutePath());
// add record log to the console
project.addBuildListener(conlog);
// add record log to the byte array
project.addBuildListener(strlog);
//
try {
  // fill the Ant project variables
  for (Entry m : map.entrySet()) {
    project.setUserProperty(m.getKey().toString(), m.getValue().toString());
  }
  project.fireBuildStarted();
  project.init();
  ProjectHelper helper = ProjectHelper.getProjectHelper();
  project.addReference("ant.projectHelper", helper);
  helper.parse(project, buildfile);
  // execute the ant task
  project.executeTarget(target);
  project.fireBuildFinished(null);
  success = true;
} catch (BuildException buildException) {
  project.fireBuildFinished(buildException);
}
// add output log to swing component (javax.swing.JTextArea)
jtLog.append(new String(outb.toByteArray()));
jtLog.append(new String(errb.toByteArray()));
return success;
```

}